# ¿Por que instanciar un objeto en el constructor de una clase?

Tags: php, objeto, instancias

por ejemplo esta clase que es parte de un crud se instancia un objeto que a su vez es una
variable declarada en la clase, mi duda es porque hacerlo así, si de todos modos se puede
instanciar el objeto sin ser declarado como variable o no?

Oh hay alguna razón por la que se hace este tipo de practicas

```
require_once 'model/alumno.entidad.php';
require_once 'model/alumno.model.php';

class AlumnoController{

private $model;

public function __CONSTRUCT(){
    $this->model = new AlumnoModel();
}

public function Index(){
    require_once 'view/header.php';
    require_once 'view/alumno/alumno.php';
    require_once 'view/footer.php';
}

public function Crud(){
    $alm = new Alumno();
    
    if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
        $alm = $this->model->Obtener($_REQUEST['id']);
    }
    
    require_once 'view/header.php';
    require_once 'view/alumno/alumno-editar.php';
    require_once 'view/footer.php';
}

public function Guardar(){
    $alm = new Alumno();
    
    $alm->__SET('id',              $_REQUEST['id']);
    $alm->__SET('Nombre',          $_REQUEST['Nombre']);
    $alm->__SET('Apellido',        $_REQUEST['Apellido']);
    $alm->__SET('Sexo',            $_REQUEST['Sexo']);
    $alm->__SET('FechaNacimiento', $_REQUEST['FechaNacimiento']);
    $alm->__SET('Correo',          $_REQUEST['Correo']);
    $alm->__SET('Foto',            $_REQUEST['Foto']);
    
    if( !empty( $_FILES['Foto']['name'] ) ){
        $foto = date('ymdhis') . '-' . strtolower($_FILES['Foto']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['Foto']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $foto);
        
        $alm->__SET('Foto', $foto);
    }

    if($alm->__GET('id') != '' ? 
       $this->model->Actualizar($alm) : 
       $this->model->Registrar($alm));
    
    header('Location: index.php');
}

public function Excel(){
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=mi_archivo.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");    
    
    require_once 'view/alumno/alumno-excel.php';
}

public function Eliminar(){
    $this->model->Eliminar($_REQUEST['id']);
    header('Location: index.php');
}
}
```

Debo decir que ese objeto se usa en otro archivo para acceder a metodos pertenecientes a su
clase

Answer (score 5):

Nada te impide declarar propiedades sobre la instancia que no están explícitamente declaradas, pero te estarías buscando problemas.

Anecdóticamente tu clase declara la propiedad en el constructor y por eso no se nota, así que vamos a hacer una clase que lo deje más en evidencia:

```
class TarjetaDeCredito 
{
    private string $cvv;
    
    public $deuda;

    public function __construct(string $cvv)
    {
        $this->cvv = $cvv;
    }

    public function autorizarCompra(int $monto, string $cvv): bool
    {
        if ($cvv !== $this->cvv) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Clave incorrecta! Abort');
        }
        $this->deuda += $monto;
        return  true;
    }

}
```

En esa clase ocurren varias cosas.

**Primero**, fíjate que hay una propiedad `$deuda`. Si yo instancio mi tarjeta de crédito y quiero ver la deuda:

```
  $tarjeta = new TarjetaDeCredito('123');
  var_dump($tarjeta->deuda);
  // imprime null
```

No se le ha asignado ningún valor a esa propiedad, pero como la he declarado es perfectamente válido acceder a ella. Por el contrario, si intento hacer lo mismo con una variable no definida como tal:

```
  var_dump($tarjeta->color);
  
  PHP Notice:  Undefined property: TarjetaDeCredito::$color in...
```

No es un error fatal y dependiendo de tu nivel de reporte de errores hasta se puede suprimir... sólo para ocupar las siguientes semanas intentando debuggear el problema.

**Corolario**: declarar la propiedad permite garantizar que existirá y podré   acceder a ella desde todos los métodos de la instancia.

---

**Segundo**, pensemos que la tarjeta se usa para hacer una compra por internet. La tienda requiere que yo tenga una tarjeta asociada a mi perfil

```
class Perfil {

  public $tarjeta;

  public function configurarTarjeta(TarjetaDeCredito $tarjeta) {
      $this->tarjeta=tarjeta;
  }

}
```

Cuando yo quiera hacer una compra, la tienda (que ya tiene mi tarjeta) me pedirá confirmar el monto e ingresar el CVV. Con eso invocará el método `autorizarCompra` en mi tarjeta. Si el CVV no corresponde ocurrirá un error y la compra será rechazada.

```
    public function autorizarCompra(int $monto, string $cvv): bool
    {
        if ($cvv !== $this->cvv) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Clave incorrecta! Abort');
        }
        $this->deuda = ($this->deuda ?? 0) + $monto;
        return  true;
    }
```

¿Qué pasaría ahí si no estuviera declarada la propiedad CVV? A simple vista se está asignando en el constructor así que me consta que nunca será indefinida aunque no esté explícitamente declarada:

```
public function __construct(string $cvv) {
    $this->cvv = $cvv;
}
```

Pero el comercio podría redeclararla y hacer una transacción sin tu autorización.

```
$tarjeta->cvv = '000';
$tarjeta->autorizar_compra(10000000,'000');
```

Lo cual no hubiera pasado si fuese una propiedad declarada explícitamente y con visibilidad privada como es ahora, porque sería secreta salvo para el que instanció esa tarjeta, e intentar asignarla arrojaría un error:

```
   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property TarjetaDeCredito::$cvv
```

**Corolario**: declarar la propiedad te permite controlar no sólo su existencia sino su visibilidad.

---

**Tercero**: la tienda quiere permitir que reasignes tu tarjeta sin usar el método `configurarTarjeta`, o sea

```
  $perfil->tarjeta = $tarjeta;
```

pero si no pasas por ese método, ¿Cómo podría la tienda estar segura de que pusiste una tarjeta y no la licencia de conducir? Bueno, podría hacerlo en la declaración de la variable, aunque esto es una adición que apareció hace no muchos años en PHP:

```
class Perfil {
   public TarjetaDeCredito $tarjeta;
}
```

Si yo intentase

```
$perfil->tarjeta = $licencia_de_conducir;
```

Saltaría un error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Typed property Perfil::$tarjeta must be an instance of TarjetaDeCredito, xxx used
```

El cual hubiese pasado desapercibido si `tarjeta` no hubiese estado declarada.

**Corolario**: en versiones recientes de PHP, declarar la propiedad te permite definir también su tipo.

**PEEERO**: por mucho que esté declarada y sea pública, acceder a ella sin haberla definido igual es un error:

```
$perfil = new Perfil();
var_dump($perfil->tarjeta);

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Typed property Perfil::$tarjeta must not be accessed before initialization
```

Esto se puede prevenir haciendo el tipo nulleable, pero apareció en la versión 7.4 apenas.

```
 public ?TarjetaDeCredito $tarjeta;
```

Que te daría `null` en vez de un error.

---

**Finalmente...** ¿Por qué PHP no te impide de plano asignar al vuelo propiedades no declaradas? Bueno, es porque sí tiene una utilidad, mediante el uso de los métodos mágicos `__set` y `__get`, que serán invocados cuando definas o intentes acceder a propiedades privadas, protegidas o no definidas.

Pensemos que la tarjeta te permite ingresar datos opcionales libremente, y gracias al método mágico `__set` éstas se almacenan en un array de llaves y valores

```
 class TarjetaDeCredito {
   private $data = [];

   public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->data[$key]=$value;
   }
   public function getData() {
      return $this->data;
   }    
 }
```

Esta implementación te permite hacer:

```
$tarjeta = new TarjetaDeCredito('1234');
$tarjeta->nombre = 'lorenzo';
$tarjeta->marca = 'VISA';

var_dump($tarjeta->getData());

array(2) {
  ["nombre"]=>
  string(7) "lorenzo"
  ["marca"]=>
  string(4) "VISA"
}
```

Sin el uso de esta implementación, ni yo mismo podría saber en otro lugar del código qué corchos le puse a esa tarjeta.*(en realidad sí se podría, con ReflectionClass, pero es overkill)* Con esta técnica en cambio pude aprovechar la permisividad de PHP para interceptar esa asignación y guiarla a una variable útil.

Junto con `__set` y `__get` hay otros métodos mágicos. En especial `__call` y `__callStatic` son una poderosa herramienta de metaprogramación y le dan una suerte de overloading que -a diferencia de Java o C#- no existe formalmente en el lenguaje.

Laravel hace uso intensivo y extensivo de estas técnicas para permitir Macros y Mixins declarados al vuelo, en el booteo del contenedor de dependencias. Pero, si esta permisividad de PHP se usa mal, lo que se logra no es comodidad sino fragilidad.

Los IDEs como PHPStorm, o VSCode con la extensión Intelephense, pueden detectar errores antes de que corras el código, apoyándose en las restricciones de visibilidad y tipo si es que te das el trabajo de ponerlos. Misma cosa ocurre con las herramientas de análisis estático como Psalm y PHPStan. Mientras más completo y explícito sea tu código, más te podrán ayudar a no pasar el 90% del proyecto odiando el código.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu pregunta no va por el camino que ha interpretado ffflabs y ya se me había ocurrido un ejemplo ilustrativo así que ...

Tengo mucha más experiencia en Java que en PHP pero como son conceptos de Programación Orientada a Objetos y de programación en general a los que haces referencia y no tengo acceso a todo tu código, espero que perdones que emplee pseudolenguaje. En POO se emplean variables miembro y estas se instancian en el constructor en lugar de instanciarse cada vez que se invoca un método por EFICIENCIA y para evitar situaciones potencialmente catastróficas para tu aplicación y las aplicaciones que se ejecutan en la misma máquina.

La eficiencia de la que te hablo esta relacionada con el uso de los recursos de la máquina, capacidad de memoria y capacidad de procesamiento, los cuales, como los del planeta, son limitados, finitos. Ten en cuenta que la situación que planteas puede extenderse por multitud de clases en un proyecto medianamente complejo, como te expongo a continuación.

Tu clase AlumnoModel es lo que se conoce como un **DAO**, un [Data Access Object](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_de_acceso_a_datos), un objeto que sirve de intermediario entre las clases de tu aplicación y una base de datos. Como tal seguramente tendrá una referencia a la conexión con dicha base de datos. En tu código tendrás algo así ...

```
class AlumnoController{

private $model;

public function __CONSTRUCT(){
    $this->model = new AlumnoModel();
}
...
}

class AlumnoModel{

private $conn;

public function __CONSTRUCT(){
    $this->conn= DBManager->getConnection();
}
...
}

class DBManager{

private $conn;

public function __CONSTRUCT(){
    $this->conn = mysql_connect(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
}
}
```

Imagina que aplicas tu política de crear los objetos en cada método cuando te hagan falta, tu método Guardar quedaría

```
public function Guardar(){

    $conn = mysql_connect(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
    $model = new AlumnoModel();
    $model.setConnection($conn);

    $alm = new Alumno();
    
    $alm->__SET('id',              $_REQUEST['id']);
    $alm->__SET('Nombre',          $_REQUEST['Nombre']);
    $alm->__SET('Apellido',        $_REQUEST['Apellido']);
    $alm->__SET('Sexo',            $_REQUEST['Sexo']);
    $alm->__SET('FechaNacimiento', $_REQUEST['FechaNacimiento']);
    $alm->__SET('Correo',          $_REQUEST['Correo']);
    $alm->__SET('Foto',            $_REQUEST['Foto']);
    
    if( !empty( $_FILES['Foto']['name'] ) ){
        $foto = date('ymdhis') . '-' . strtolower($_FILES['Foto']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['Foto']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $foto);
        
        $alm->__SET('Foto', $foto);
    }

    if($alm->__GET('id') != '' ? 
       $model->Actualizar($alm) : 
       $model->Registrar($alm));
    
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Como ves he tenido que añadir tres líneas más al método. Tres líneas que habría que añadir a todos los métodos de tu clase AlumnoController. Y que habría que añadir a todos los métodos de los otros controladores, ProfesorController, MatriculaController, ...

Por si esto no fuera poco, cuando se crea un objeto, se reserva un espacio en memoria para él, que el motor del lenguaje se encarga de liberar cuando el objeto deja de usarse. Esta parte del motor se conoce como **Garbage Collector**. Esta detección y liberación de memoria tienen un coste de procesamiento adicional. También hay que tener en cuenta que la operación de apertura de una conexión a base de datos es relativamente costosa, ya que hay que transmitir por la red los datos del usuario, validarlos, reservar los recursos necesarios para esa conexión en el servidor de base de datos y enviar la respuesta indicando que la conexión se ha establecido satisfactoriamente.

El número de conexiones abiertas que puede tener un servidor de base de datos también es finito. Dichos servidores son capaces de detectar que una conexión está inactiva durante un tiempo para liberarla y dejarla disponible.

Podemos intentar agilizar el tiempo que tarda nuestro motor del lenguaje en detectar que un objeto ya no está referenciado para que libere la memoria y el tiempo que tarda el servidor de la base de datos en detectar que una conexión está inactiva, invocando métodos especiales de liberación. Los cuales no garantizan que la liberación sea inmediata. Algo como lo siguiente.

```
public function Guardar(){

        $conn = mysql_connect(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        $model = new AlumnoModel();
        $model.setConnection($conn);

        $alm = new Alumno();
        
        $alm->__SET('id',              $_REQUEST['id']);
        $alm->__SET('Nombre',          $_REQUEST['Nombre']);
        $alm->__SET('Apellido',        $_REQUEST['Apellido']);
        $alm->__SET('Sexo',            $_REQUEST['Sexo']);
        $alm->__SET('FechaNacimiento', $_REQUEST['FechaNacimiento']);
        $alm->__SET('Correo',          $_REQUEST['Correo']);
        $alm->__SET('Foto',            $_REQUEST['Foto']);
        
        if( !empty( $_FILES['Foto']['name'] ) ){
            $foto = date('ymdhis') . '-' . strtolower($_FILES['Foto']['name']);
            move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['Foto']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $foto);
            
            $alm->__SET('Foto', $foto);
        }
    
        if($alm->__GET('id') != '' ? 
           $model->Actualizar($alm) : 
           $model->Registrar($alm));
      
        $model->Destroy();
        $conn->Close();

        header('Location: index.php');
    }
```

Ya hemos añadido 5 líneas a este método que antes no estaban. Las cuales hay que multiplicar por todos los métodos y controllers. Cientos de líneas que se suman a las que ya hay para otras cosas. Mientras más lineas de código haya, posteriormente será más difícil encontrar un error en el código cuando se detecte una incidencia.

Comparemos esta situación con un ejemplo de la vida real. Imagina que das una fiesta en tu casa a tus 20 mejores amigos con la peculiaridad de que les indicas que cada vez que quieran UNA patata frita (invocar un método), abran una bolsa NUEVA (instanciar un nuevo objeto) y la tiren al suelo que ya te pasarás tú a RECOGERLA (collect, liberación de recursos). Cuando se acaben las bolsas, te acercarás a la tienda del barrio a por más (establecer conexión a la base de datos).

Al principio todo irá bien, has comprado muchas bolsas de patatas y las vas recogiendo del suelo tan contento. Pero en un momento dado te pondrás con la barbacoa y las bolsas de patatas se irán acumulando en el suelo.

Mientras estás encendiendo la barbacoa, alguien te dice que se han acabado las patatas. Vas a la tienda y compras todas las bolsas. Imagina cómo estará el suelo de tu patio o de tu salón cuando vuelvas. Porque la gente ha aplicado lo de UNA patata, una NUEVA bolsa y al SUELO con todas las viandas de la fiesta: aceitunas, cacahuetes, botellas de refrescos, latas de cerveza, ... Vas a estar más ocupando limpiando que disfrutando de la fiesta. Y ten en cuenta que cuando se acaben las patatas otra vez tendrás que ir por más a otra tienda, una que está más lejos.

El ejemplo está muy exagerado pero creo que refleja bien los conceptos implicados. Si tu aplicación usa base de datos establece la conexión una sola vez. Si tu aplicación lee un fichero de propiedades de configuración cárgalo una sola vez y accede a la referencia donde lo has cargado cuando lo necesites. Si tu aplicación administra alumnos, instancia una sola vez el AlumnoModel. Realiza una sola vez las operaciones costosas en tiempo como establecimiento de conexiones o lectura de disco y no desperdicies recursos innecesariamente.

A ver, no es que tengas miedo de crear nuevos objetos, pero ten en cuenta que esto es lo que pasa por detrás. Y por esto se usan referencias en lugar de crear instancias nuevas cada vez.

Comment: Es una buena acotación. En PHP no tendrías cómo asignar una instancia de la clase A a una variable de la clase B, pero sí podrías asignar una constante escalar de muchos megas. Eso en cuanto a la conveniencia de mantenerla indefinida hasta que no se instancie. Lo otro ya entra en un plano de arquitectura más que de paradigma.

Comment: bien muchas gracias por la explicación bien detallada en verdad agradezco mucho el detalle porque me inicio en la programación y esto me hace entender bastante bien, en pocas palabras el hecho de hacer ese tipo de practicas es para ahorrar los recursos de la máquina

Comment: @lorenzo De nada, hombre. Como curiosidad de abuelete programador, el propio nombre del sitio original, StackOverflow, habla de esa finitud de recursos. Ese es un error que se da cuando una función se llama recursivamente a si misma infinitamente y se acaba el espacio en la pila (stack) de llamadas y se produce un desborde (overflow).